# Statically linking a library into a C++ dylib on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, static-linking, dylib

I am compiling a number of .dylibs (a plugins) and I want to statically include tinyxml2 into them.
I've got `tinyxml2.cpp` and `tinyxml2.h` sitting next to the sources. When I run my make, the commands it produces are:

```
rm -rf *.a *.os *.dylib
g++-4.0 -g -c -Werror -DUSE_GLEW -I/Applications/Nuke6.3v4/Nuke6.3v4.app/Contents/MacOS/include -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -arch x86_64 tinyxml2.cpp -o tinyxml2.a
g++-4.0 -g -c -Werror -DUSE_GLEW -I/Applications/Nuke6.3v4/Nuke6.3v4.app/Contents/MacOS/include -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -arch x86_64 -o SyGeo.os SyGeo.cpp
g++-4.0 -L/Applications/Nuke6.3v4/Nuke6.3v4.app/Contents/MacOS -Wl,-syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -arch x86_64 -bundle -lDDImage -lGLEW -framework QuartzCore -framework IOKit -framework CoreFoundation -framework Carbon -framework ApplicationServices -framework OpenGL -framework AGL  -o SyGeo.dylib SyGeo.os
Undefined symbols:
  "tinyxml2::XMLDocument::LoadFile(char const*)", referenced from:
      SyDistorter::readPreset()       in SyGeo.os
  "tinyxml2::XMLDocument::~XMLDocument()", referenced from:
      SyDistorter::readPreset()       in SyGeo.os
      SyDistorter::readPreset()       in SyGeo.os
  "tinyxml2::XMLElement::FindAttribute(char const*) const", referenced from:
      tinyxml2::XMLElement::QueryFloatAttribute(char const*, float*) constin SyGeo.os
  "tinyxml2::XMLNode::NextSiblingElement(char const*) const", referenced from:
      tinyxml2::XMLNode::NextSiblingElement(char const*)in SyGeo.os
  "tinyxml2::XMLDocument::XMLDocument(bool)", referenced from:
      SyDistorter::readPreset()       in SyGeo.os
  "tinyxml2::XMLNode::FirstChildElement(char const*) const", referenced from:
      tinyxml2::XMLNode::FirstChildElement(char const*)in SyGeo.os
  "tinyxml2::XMLAttribute::QueryFloatValue(float*) const", referenced from:
      tinyxml2::XMLElement::QueryFloatAttribute(char const*, float*) constin SyGeo.os
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [SyGeo.dylib] Error 1
```

How should I proceed to make it link? (I want all the .dylibs that I am building to include the tinyxml2 lib statically, preferably with namespace mangling).

Note that I am using the older 10.5 SDK here - I have to since my host application uses it.

Comment: Add `tinyxml2.a` after `SyGeo.os` when you create SyGeo.dylib.

Comment: You mean in the link command or in the compile command?

Comment: The link command/the 3rd one/the one that creates `SyGeo.dylib`.

Comment: It works! Thanks alot! If you move your comment to an answer I'll flag it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When linking you'll to specify all object files needed. So add `tinyxml2.a` after `SyGeo.os` when linking to create `SyGeo.dylib`.